# Блок чуть ниже другого блока

Tags: css

Здравствуйте.

Есть такая конструкция:

```
    <div id="navbar">

    </div>
    <div id="abody">

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #1e64cc;
    height: 5%;
    width: 100%;
}
#abody {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    height: auto;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Вроде бы, отступ от верхнего блока в 1% есть, во всех браузерах отображается корректно, кроме IE. Там идет отступ от самого начала страницы (самый верх), а от блока отступа никакого нет. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так http://jsfiddle.net/F2wsG/1/

там добавилось html, body {height: 100%;}